# Trying to identify an obscure and barely remembered 1970s TV series

Tags: story-identification, tv

This has been bugging me for years.
So this would have been mid 1970s when I was between 6-10 and it was aimed at kids that age because it was a series on a kids TV show (probably channel 9 Aus). I'm in Aus but I'm pretty sure it wasn't Australian. US, Canada or UK.

I don't remember much but what I do remember is that it was (of course) a group of kids trying to stop some bad adult guys. There was at least one girl.
One scene had the bad guys in a car being stopped at some boom-gate type  entrance by a guard and they used a bike pump / old insect spray pump device to spray some gas into (her?) face that rendered (her?) incapacitated and made to speak in a helium voice. I think the spraying of gas at people was kind of a thing in this series.
The only other scene I remember was that a male boy protagonist was sprayed and suddenly got super revved up - speedy (film speeded up) so they tethered him to a stake in the backyard and let him run around in circles until it wore off.

Not much to go on I know.

Comment: Was the 'speeding up' the only sci-fi element of the show?

Comment: There were a lot of weird devices that made people act strangely. There was also I think a scientist who was helping the kids.

Comment: This sounds a bit like "Nightmare Gas" from Ace of Wands - an ITV (British) show from 1970 - 1972.  I don't know how to post quotes, but this is from IMDB "The theft of a deadly hallucinatory gas, H23, by the deadly Thalia and her brother Dalbiac, plunges Tarot and his friends into a nightmare adventure. Contact with the gas induces deep sleep and nightmares so real that the victim dies from shock after 23 minutes: captured and exposed to the gas, Tarot has only minutes to live."  No mention of speeding up or helium voices, but does any of that sound familiar?